# Unix script: use of date and use of for

Tags: unix, script, date

MinuteNow=`date +%M`;

```
for ((i=2;i<=57;i+=5))
do
        if [ "$MinuteNow" == "$i" ]; then
                *************
        fi
done
```

The problem is for 2 and 7, the date commande output is 02 and 07 but the variable $i is 2 and 7... I tried to add a condition to change only these 2, but it was bugging the loop...

Can you give me a tip please?

Comment: Unix is an operating system. Saying "how do I do X in a Unix script" is like "how do I do X in a Windows programming language" without telling _which_ of the hundred languages you use.

Answer (score 2):

Use "-eq" to compare numbers, then you wont have this problems:

```
if [ "$MinuteNow" -eq "$i" ]; then
```

should do it.

(there are lots of other possibilities, being ${MinuteNow#0} another simple one, but I thing using the right operator -eq instead of == is the better one).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 [ $MinuteNow -eq $i ]
```

See [***man test***](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=test) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you will need to force the string to base 10:

```
if (( 10#$MinuteNow == i ))    # you can omit the dollar sign on bare variables in this context
```

In the Bourne shell (sh):

```
if [ $MinuteNow -eq $i ]
```

In zsh or ksh93:

```
if (( MinuteNow == i ))    # you can omit the dollar sign on bare variables in this context
```

Answer (score 0):

In **`bash`**, use:

```
(( $MinuteNow == $i ))
```

as in:

```
if (( $MinuteNow == $i )); then
```

---

If **`sh`** compatibility is needed, use:

```
[ "$MinuteNow" -eq "$i" ]
```